# Are there any concerns using an object to store data retrieved from a server?

Tags: android, kotlin

Will the Object be around for as long as the app is in the background? Does anyone know when a Kotlin Object get removed from memory and reset in Android? Should I just use a ViewModel instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is in the background, you can't know what the system will do with it so you can't store in memory data you want to persist.
You have different solutions:

- If it's data from a server, you can make the call again if the app has been destroyed between the moment the user put it in the background and the app is brought back.
- You can store the data locally.

In the second case you have 3 solutions:

- Persist the data into a SQL database, using a solution like Room for instance. This is usually the way to do it.
- Persist the data into the Shared Preferences. Used for light data, like settings or small preferences
- Store them into a file (usually not a good approach)

A ViewModel is **not** a way to persist data. It will only persist data in memory. It is good to keep the data when the **UI** has been destroyed (app changes orientation, or Fragment put in the backstack for instance)
But if the app is killed (for any reason), so will be the ViewModel and everything it contains.

However following a MVP or MVVM (using ViewModel) pattern is a good way to build you app as it decouples the UI from the logic and helps with tests.

Comment: For my case, it is best to store the data in a room database and update it when connected to wifi or forced request. Thank you for the detailed answer that very much clarified my understanding.